# PFB Embedded in PDF gives PDF/ACompliance Error

Tags: pdf

I'm generating a PDF file using a **.pfb** file for Arial font.

The font is embedded but **Vera Checker** gives me the following error:

[image]

Most probably there's something related to the way I embed it in the pdf.
I uploaded [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/37c9e489d8b56c4c3b965b6ddf811fd720210830080954/c98484) both the **.pfb** and the **.pdf** files

Comment: *"I uploaded here"* - where "here"?

Comment: Added them now @mkl